# Change Navbar-brand color on certain page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to change the color of `.navbar-brand` when it reaches a certain page of the website?
I currently have this code which changes its color when scrolled:

```
.navbar-brand.scrolled {
  color: yellow !important;
  transition: 200ms linear;
}
```

and the script:

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    var $nav = $(".navbar-brand");
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reaches a certain page of the website"?

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson on my website, I have the following pages: home, stories, and articles. My navbar-brand's color by default is black, is it possible for it to change when it reaches the "articles" page only?

Comment: You may want to have a global CSS file that you reference on all pages and an articles CSS file that you only include on that page and override the default styles that you want to change. There's countless ways to go about this though.

Answer (score 0):

Put class="articles" on < body > maybe of page articles, then use that selector with CSS.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.articles nav {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<body class="articles">
  <nav>

  </nav>
</body>
```